# webpack.config.js: setting for uncompressing css and javascript

Tags: webpack

Background: this is the first time I have seen webpack.config.js

Here is the webpack.config.js
https://github.com/marcom-unimelb/unimelb-design-system/blob/master/assets/webpack.config.js

The generated output javascript and css based on the config above are all minified. I need to have them unminfied and wonder what should I do?

What I understand is that, I need to do something here.

```
preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // include .js files
        exclude: /node_modules|vendor/, // exclude any and all files in the node_modules folder
        loader: "jshint-loader"
      }
    ],
```

and here:

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader?-minimize!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader")
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader?-minimize!autoprefixer-loader")
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a line like this at **package.json**:

```
"build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config ./assets/webpack.config.js -p"
```

It's that `-p` flag there that triggers minification (p for production I think). If you remove the flag, you'll get an unminified build.

Comment: I was told that webpack.config.js is the place to look at. I used the "exact" webpack.config.js with smaller javascript codebase e.g. a hello world program. I discover that webpack.config.js wouldn't compress/uncompress css/javascript at all. By using grep (Linux command), I found out all files containing 'webpack' and eventually ping point package.json is the file I need to modify.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes configuration can be tricky like that. Webpack allows you to split it between the cli and `webpack.config.js`. Personally I maintain just keep the cli side simple (just `webpack`) and branch at configuration through [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge).